# Python обьединить несколько exception

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
    try:
        """ Не важно """

    except ValueError:
        sending_list.remove(one_channel)
        PiarChats.all_list = sending_list
        await tobase.remove_dead_channel(sending_list)

    except TypeError:
        sending_list.remove(one_channel)
        PiarChats.all_list = sending_list
        await tobase.remove_dead_channel(sending_list)

    except UsernameInvalidError:
        sending_list.remove(one_channel)
        PiarChats.all_list = sending_list
        await tobase.remove_dead_channel(sending_list)
```

Как их обьединить. Так? -> `except TypeError, ValueError, UsernameError:`

Comment: Неуверен, но попробуйте так: `except error in [TypeError, ValueError, UsernameError]:`

Comment: Не думаю, что правильное решение, но вдруг поможет)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html

Answer (score 5):

```
except (ValueError, TypeError, UsernameInvalidError) as e:
    sending_list.remove(one_channel)
    PiarChats.all_list = sending_list
    await tobase.remove_dead_channel(sending_list)
```